# What is the connection between Refs and Broadcasting in Julia

Tags: julia

For two objects `A` and `B` we could previously get the vector `[A*A, A*B]` with the code `A .* [A, B]`. From the deprecation warnings in Julia 0.7, it seems that the new way to do this is to use a reference of the first A. So it becomes `Ref(A) .* [A,B]`.

It doesn't seem that there is a strong link between references and broadcasting operations. What is the link here and why is using a Reference preferred (by the deprecation warnings at least)?

### Minimal Working Example

```
import Base.*
struct example
    num::Int
end
function *(lhs::example, rhs::example)
    return example(lhs.num * rhs.num)
end
A = example(2)
B = example(4)
# Previously this could be done as follows.
A .* [A, B]
# Now we need to use Refs
Ref(A) .* [A, B]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will here refer to the main case of `Ref`, that is when you pass it one argument (there are also other subtypes of `Ref` but they are not relevant for us here).
Writing `Ref(x)` creates a mutable wrapper around object `x`. The wrapper is a very simple `RefValue` type defined in the following way:

```
mutable struct RefValue{T} <: Ref{T}
    x::T
    RefValue{T}() where {T} = new()
    RefValue{T}(x) where {T} = new(x)
end
```

Now why it is useful, because `Ref` has defined the following utility functions:

```
eltype(x::Type{<:Ref{T}}) where {T} = @isdefined(T) ? T : Any
size(x::Ref) = ()
axes(x::Ref) = ()
length(x::Ref) = 1
ndims(x::Ref) = 0
ndims(::Type{<:Ref}) = 0
iterate(r::Ref) = (r[], nothing)
iterate(r::Ref, s) = nothing
IteratorSize(::Type{<:Ref}) = HasShape{0}()
```

which means that it can be used in broadcasting as only objects that have `axes` defined and support indexing can be used with `broadcast`.

Fortunately it is easy to avoid writing `Ref(A)` all the time.

Just define:

```
Base.broadcastable(e::example) = Ref(e)
```

and the machinery of `broadcast` will work again as `Base.broadcastable` is called on each argument of `broadcast`.

More details about customizing broadcasting can be found here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interfaces-broadcasting.

Comment: So basically `Ref` here is used as 0-dimensional Array?

Comment: It behaves almost the same. A tiny difference is that `iterate(x)[2]` is `2` for `0`-dimensional array and `nothing` for `Ref`, but this should not matter much.

Comment: And one more thing `Ref` is not a subtype of `AbstractArray` so it will behave differently in dispatch, e.g. in cases where a method requires `AbstractArray` argument.